# Скрипт для занесения значений из одной таблицы в другие

Tags: скрипт, mysql, sql-server, sql

Добрый день.
Есть таблицы `ForInsert` с полями `[Vopros,A,B,C,D,E]`

```
             Voprosi            [IdVoprosa,Vopros,Buffer(?)]
             Varianti           [IdVoprosa,IdVarianta,Variant,IsTrue]
```

Как мне из таблицы `ForInsert [Vopros]` занести значения в `Voprosi [Vopros]`, затем получить `IdVoprosa` и записать в таблицу `Varianti [IdVoprosa,Variant,IsTrue=true]` из `ForInsert           [A]` для варианта A и `Varianti [IdVoprosa,Variant,IsTrue=false]` из `ForInsert` для значений с полей B, C, D, E.

Ещё такой момент - вопросы могут повторятся. Т.е. вносится  вопрос и ставим, например, `Voprosi            [Buffer=true]` потом для получения `IdVoprosa` ищем такой же вопрос с `[Buffer=true]` ->берём `IdVoprosa` (что б не попасть случайно на другой точно такой же по тексту вопрос) и делаем `[Buffer=false]`.
Ну, как-то так.
Подскажите, как это реализовать?
Спасибо.

Comment: А чем dense_rank не устраивает?

Comment: А сам механизм скрипта не подскажите?

Comment: Вставить в таблицу вопросов, вставить в таблицу вариантов, профит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Триггер перед вставкой, обращающийся к процедуре

```
CREATE 
    DEFINER = 'root'@'%'
TRIGGER test.trigger1
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON test.TableForInsert
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  CALL InsertVoprosProcedure(New.Vopros,New.A,New.B,New.C,New.D,New.E);
END
```

И процедура

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'%'
PROCEDURE test.InsertVoprosProcedure(IN inVopros varchar(255),IN inA varchar(255),IN inB varchar(255),IN inC varchar(255),IN inD varchar(255),IN inE varchar(255))
BEGIN
    insert into voprosi (Vopros) values (inVopros);

    SELECT MAX(Id)  FROM voprosi INTO @maxId;     //  Узнаёт последний занесенный вопрос

    IF inA<>"" then
      insert into Varianti (IdVoprosa,Variant,IsTrue) values (@maxId,inA,1);
    END IF;

    IF inB<>"" then
      insert into Varianti (IdVoprosa,Variant,IsTrue) values (@maxId,inB,0);
    END IF;

     IF inC<>"" then
      insert into Varianti (IdVoprosa,Variant,IsTrue) values (@maxId,inC,0);
    END IF;

    IF inD<>"" then
      insert into Varianti (IdVoprosa,Variant,IsTrue) values (@maxId,inD,0);
    END IF;

    IF inE<>"" then
      insert into Varianti (IdVoprosa,Variant,IsTrue) values (@maxId,inE,0);
    END IF;
END
```